# Multiprocessing for loop in Tkinter App

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, tkinter, python-multiprocessing

I have some code with a GUI that takes a series of files and performs a set of calculations, and produces some corresponding graphs and files. Everything I have read says to use multiprocessing to help speed this process up. The issue I am having is that tkinter is blocking any multiprocessing.

Here is my example code

```
class ClassLess(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.root = parent
        self.init_gui()

    def calculate_setup(self):
        #Load files into self.files
        pool = Pool(os.cpu_count())
        pool.map(self.calculate, self.files)

    def calculate(self, file):
        result = file + 2

    def init_gui(self):
        self.root.title('Example')
        self.root.option_add('*tearOff', 'FALSE')
        self.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='nsew')
        self.menubar = tkinter.Menu(self.root)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    ClassLess(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Whenever I run this I get the error:
     TypeError: can't pickle _tkinter.tkapp objects

The only hint I have found is that maybe I cannot use multiprocessing in the child of a tkinter parent?

Comment: The hint you got is correct. Only the main process should use tkinter. Have the other processes communicate with it through a `Queue` or other inter-process communications mechanism.

Comment: One other thing, if `calculate` doesn't actually use anything from the class you can make it a free function.

Comment: I tried setting the calculate function outside of the class, but the issue that comes up is calling the instances created in calculate_setup. I have always had the issue with the parent argument in these situations. Is there a way to get past setting parent? I can't exactly call another ttk frame or set it to none.